# Mysql Query returning record count is more than returning rows

Tags: mysql

Mysql query giving only one record but the count function giving count more than one.

[edit]
My basic aim to get count of user who attempted the survey. and in table each row represent the answer of each question in survey. so each row contain user id.

**Database table Schema(table):**

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| survey_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| user_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

**Data in Table(table):**

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| id | survey_id | user_id |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 |         1 |       1 |
|  2 |         1 |       1 |
|  3 |         1 |       1 |
+----+-----------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

COUNT Query :

```
SELECT count(*) AS total FROM `table` WHERE survey_id = 1 GROUP BY user_id
```

Result:

```
+-------+
| total |
+-------+
|     3 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And Simple query:

```
SELECT id,user_id,survey_id AS total FROM `table` WHERE survey_id = 1 GROUP BY user_id
```

Result:

```
+----+---------+-------+
| id | user_id | total |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 |       1 |     1 |
+----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Desire Result:**

The count and number of row(s) should be same.

so, why second query returning single row and first count query returning not one.

let me know if still unclear anything.

Any help would be appreciable in advance.

Comment: Because you are misusing `GROUP BY`.  Its purpose is for aggregates like `COUNT()/SUM()/MAX()/MIN()` and MySQL permits you to use it as you have, without all `SELECT` list columns grouped, but with unexpected and indeterminate results. Did you mean to use `ORDER BY user_id`?

Comment: can you provide me best way to use Group by with count function in query?

Comment: It is unclear _why_ you want to use `GROUP BY`, since it is intended for use with aggregate functions. Post the query result you are trying to achieve, please.

Comment: Well, in my case count should be one.

Comment: The aggregate `COUNT()` is a bit different from _the number of rows that would be returned_. Are you looking for `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html

Comment: Please edit your question above to include exactly the result you are looking for, all columns and rows, so people answering have a complete picture without having to read this confusing comment thread.

Comment: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table WHERE survey_id = 1;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() cnt;` 
yeah Its giving me the required result. but can we convert this two query into one query?

Comment: Michael, thank you so much for your comments, my major focus to get behind this behavior instead of required result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count the number of groups `GROUP BY` returns you can use `COUNT(distinct user_id)`

Comment: can you explain why we want to use distinct in count function in that scenario.

Comment: if you just want to count the number of groups this is correct, as distinct only counts each user_id once

Comment: can you explain  to get understanding behind this behavior? still unclear to me.

Comment: count distinct counts each user_id only once, so in your example the id 1 occurs 3 times, but count distinct only counts it once